# ライブラリとフレームワークの違いとは？

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

ライブラリとフレームワークの違いとはなんでしょうか。
G検定の勉強をしていたら
NumPy
scikit-learn
が、ライブラリの説明の箇所でもフレームワークの説明の箇所でも登場しました。
両者はたまたま両方にまたがるものなんでしょうか？

Comment: どういった文脈での説明なのか、実際の記述を (出典を明記した上で) 引用で示してもらうと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: この辺の記事の関係でしょうか。[G検定（ジェネラリスト検定）とは？【データサイエンティストに関わる資格】](https://www.agaroot.jp/datascience/column/deep-learning-for-general/), [Pythonフレームワークのまとめ【2022年版】](https://freelance-start.com/articles/69), [【Python】フレームワークとライブラリの違いは？](https://tetsumag.com/2022/09/13/505/), [【解説】フレームワークとライブラリの違い](https://zenn.dev/nameless_sn/articles/framework_and_library), [Pythonのモジュールとパッケージとライブラリとフレームワークの違い](https://webbigdata.jp/what-is-ai/page-6804/page-8359/page-12091), [Pythonフレームワークの概要からおすすめソフトウェアまで紹介](https://and-engineer.com/articles/YhraURAAACMArXSy)

Comment: 文脈によって異なってくるものなんでしょうか？

Comment: 公式なドキュメントやWikipediaではライブラリと書いてありますね。[NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/), [NumPy - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [Getting Started - scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html), [scikit-learn - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn) しかしscikit-learnの方はframeworkと紹介する記事もあります。[Scikit-learn, TensorFlow, PyTorch, Keras… but where to begin?](https://towardsdatascience.com/9b499e2547d0), [Top 20 Machine Learning Frameworks You Must Know](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/best-machine-learning-frameworks/) 記事を書く人の考え方次第では？

Comment: [tag:javascript]についての記事ですが、[フレームワークとライブラリの違い](https://qiita.com/kotaro-caffeinism/items/23342d90c01f6f114405)を見つけました。

Answer (score 3):

私はこんなイメージです。矢印が呼び出しの向きを表しています。

[image: フレームワークとライブラリのイメージ]

Comment: "制御の反転"とか"ハリウッドの原則"と呼ばれているやつですね。https://xtech.nikkei.com/it/article/lecture/20070205/260697/

Answer (score 0):

### 回答ではありません

ただのWikipediaの引用です。
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

> Frameworks have key distinguishing features that separate them from normal libraries:
>
> ```
> inversion of control: In a framework, unlike in libraries or in standard user applications, the overall program's flow of control is not dictated by the caller, but by the framework.[1] This is usually achieved with the Template Method Pattern.
> default behaviour: This can be provided with the invariant methods of the Template Method Pattern in an abstract class which is provided by the framework.
> extensibility: A user can extend the framework – usually by selective overriding – or programmers can add specialized user code to provide specific functionality. This is usually achieved by a hook method in a subclass that overrides a template method in the superclass.
> non-modifiable framework code: The framework code, in general, is not supposed to be modified, while accepting user-implemented extensions. In other words, users can extend the framework, but cannot modify its code.
> ```

**余談:**
個人的にはinversion of control(制御の反転)を主軸にした説明が多い気がします。こういう言葉の定義ほどどうでもいいことはない気もしますけど。